# Registro de nombres separar columnas

Tags: r, string, datatable, str

Soy nuevo en R y estoy teniendo problemas para organizar una base de datos que contiene diferentes nombres.

Quiero separar el string en columnas pero el problema es que cada valor tiene una configuración diferente.

`Nombres <- c("Alarcon Rodriguez Juan Ignacio", "Rojas Maria", "Diaz Flores Tomas")`

**Estoy pensando en ocupar un str_count(pattern = " ") junto a diferentes if statement para que, en base a la cantidad de espacios en blanco, separe las columnas como las siguientes**:

***#Ejemplo df inicial***

```
Nombres <- c("Alarcon Rodriguez Juan Ignacio", "Rojas Maria", "Diaz Flores Tomas", "Herrera Castro Maria Teresita de Jesus")

id <- 1:4

df1 <- data.table(id,Nombres)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***#Ejemplo df buscado***

```
Apellido1 <- c("Alarcon", "Rojas", "Diaz", "Herrera")
Apellido2 <- c("Rodriguez", "NA", "Flores", "Castro")
Nombre1 <- c("Juan", "Maria", "Tomas", "Maria")
Nombre2 <- c("Ignacio", "NA", "NA", "Teresita de Jesus")


df2 <- data.table(id,Apellido1, Apellido2, Nombre1, Nombre2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que se entienda, desde ya les agradezco infinito por su ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido Fernandoibs, el tuyo es un problema  bastante típico, pero lamentablemente no tiene solución, una persona con tres nombres  y con un solo apellido, ya rompe la lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que...

0. Preparar
1. Identificar
2. Reemplazar
3. Separar
4. Combinar
5. Reemplazar otra vez
6. Finalizar

```
# --- 0. Preparar

require( purrr )
require( stringi )
require( tibble )

Nombres <- c(
   "Alarcon Rodriguez Juan Ignacio"
 , "Rojas Maria"
 , "Diaz Flores Tomas"
 , "Herrera Castro Maria Teresita de Jesus"
)

cfg <- list(
  COLUMNAS = c( 'Apellido1', 'Apellido2', 'Nombre1', 'Nombre2' )
)
cfg$MAX_PARTES <- length( cfg$COLUMNAS )

# --- 1. Identificar nombres como 'Teresita de Jesus', 'Enrique de los Angeles', ...

sustituciónes <- tribble(
     ~A         ,  ~B
  , ' de '       , '_de_'
  , ' de las '   , '_de_las_'
  , ' de los '   , '_de_los_'
  # otros sustituciónes ...
)

# --- 2. Reemplazar con `_`

U <- stri_replace_all_regex(
    Nombres
  , pattern     = sustituciónes$A
  , replacement = sustituciónes$B
  , vectorize   = FALSE
)

U
#[1] "Alarcon Rodriguez Juan Ignacio"         "Rojas Maria"                           
#[3] "Diaz Flores Tomas"                      "Herrera Castro Maria Teresita_de_Jesus"

# --- 3. Separar

V <- strsplit( U, ' ' )

V
#[[1]]
#[1] "Alarcon"   "Rodriguez" "Juan"      "Ignacio"  
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "Rojas" "Maria"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "Diaz"   "Flores" "Tomas" 
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "Herrera"           "Castro"            "Maria"             "Teresita_de_Jesus"

# --- 4. Combinar

N <- sapply( V, length ) %>% data.frame

N
#  .
#1 4
#2 2
#3 3
#4 4

g <- function( V, N, i, M = cfg$MAX_PARTES ){
  nombre_entero <- V[[ i ]]
  partes <- N[ i, 1 ]
  falta  <- M - partes
  c(
      nombre_entero
    , rep( x = '', times = falta )
  )
}

seq( nrow( N )) %>%
  map( ~g( V, N, .x) ) %>%
    unlist( recursive = FALSE ) ->
      W

W
# [1] "Alarcon"           "Rodriguez"         "Juan"              "Ignacio"          
# [5] "Rojas"             "Maria"             ""                  ""                 
# [9] "Diaz"              "Flores"            "Tomas"             ""                 
#[13] "Herrera"           "Castro"            "Maria"             "Teresita_de_Jesus"

# --- 5. Reemplazar otra vez
 
X <- stri_replace_all_regex(
    W
  , pattern     = sustituciónes$B
  , replacement = sustituciónes$A
  , vectorize   = FALSE
)      
 
X
# [1] "Alarcon"           "Rodriguez"         "Juan"              "Ignacio"          
# [5] "Rojas"             "Maria"             ""                  ""                 
# [9] "Diaz"              "Flores"            "Tomas"             ""                 
#[13] "Herrera"           "Castro"            "Maria"             "Teresita de Jesus"

# --- 6. Finalizar

matrix( X, byrow = TRUE, ncol = cfg$MAX_PARTES ) %>%
  data.frame %>% setNames( cfg$COLUMNAS ) ->
    df

df
#  Apellido1 Apellido2 Nombre1           Nombre2
#1   Alarcon Rodriguez    Juan           Ignacio
#2     Rojas     Maria                          
#3      Diaz    Flores   Tomas                  
#4   Herrera    Castro   Maria Teresita de Jesus
```